# how to invisible Google Zoom control and make my own zoom control?

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

I shown google map in my application but in that I want to make default zoom control instead I want to make my own zoom control. I tried `map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);` but showing map can not be resolved.

code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read this : http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html

Comment: what is map in map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false); please explain also i want to add a button that perform the function of zoom in and another that perform zoom out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable default zoom buttons by using:

```
map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

**UPDATE**:

```
import java.util.Map;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap googleMap ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }
    if (googleMap == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, Unable to Load Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    googleMap .getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

// Then add two buttons on map where ever you need then perform on click action like:

findViewById(R.id.zoom_in_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
            }
        });
findViewById(R.id.zoom_out_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
            }
        });
}
}
```

Comment: thanks lot:-) and i am getting error like "map" can not be resolved.please help

Comment: package com.example.googlemap;

    import java.util.Map;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
 }
    }

Comment: you need to get the Google map

Comment: i have tried to put two buttons to make zoom in and out control but in xml file i created fragment can i add button element also?how to add it into the xml file please give solution

Comment: i have now disabled zoom controls in map and now how can i code to set zoom control to buttons

Comment: @user3913537 Updated try it now

Answer (score 0):

By your code your problem is that you are not getting an instance of the GoogleMap object that you defined in your XML file, you need to run this method on your onCreate of the `Activity`:

```
 private void initializeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }
    if (googleMap == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, Unable to Load Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Make sure you will change the `R.id.map` to the proper `id` from your xml file.

Comment: i have doubt in anonymous class can you please clarify it.

Comment: I don't really understand you question, and It's doesn't really matter because you already accpeted an answer on this question. If you have another question, please open another post to discus it.